# Trying to combine resultset from two tables using key in MySQL

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables of data, `songs` and `files` in a MySQL database thus:

Songs table:

```
  song_id   |   song_title    |
     1      |     A Title     |
     2      |     B Title     |
```

Files table:

```
  file_id   |    file_name    |  parent_id  |
    1       |    asong.mp3    |     1       |
    2       |    bsong.mp3    |     1       |
```

I'd like to make one SQL query to return a set like this (where song_id = 1):

```
song_id => 1
song_title => A Title
song_files = Array(
     0 => Array(
            file_id => 1
            file_name => asong.mp3
          )
     1 => Array(
            file_id => 2
            file_name => bsong.mp3
          )
)
```

Ideally, I only want to query the database once, and have been exploring JOINs, but I'm not convinced that is the method I need. I'm using PHP 5

Many thanks!
Olly

Comment: why did you say you don't need join? I assume your parent_id references the song? Join would be the way to go. `SELECT file_id, file_name FROM files JOIN songs ON files.parent_id = songs.song_id`

Comment: There are two ways to get that, first is using join, while second just using where clauses

Comment: So, the query to use must be SELECT song_id, file_id, parent_id FROM songs, files WHERE parent_id = song_id

Comment: I'm assuming that parent_id is a foreign key referenced to song_id. Is it right? If its ok, then you must use inner join clause

Comment: parent_id seems weird to me. Wouldn't your where be song_id=file_id. The parent_id column doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Thanks guys. Tunmise, you were right JOIN was the way to go. I've just done some custom formatting on the resultset to get it into the array format I need. I guess I was thinking that one query would be able to return an array in a very specific form. But Obviously, I just needed to run it through a loop and format it myself.

Anyways, Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function, which returns a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) of values, like this:

```
select song_id, song_title, group_concat(file_name) as file_names
from songs
join files on files.parent_id = songs.song_id
group by 1, 2
```

The result would look like:

```
song_id | song_title | file_names
---------------------------------------------------
1       | A Title    | asong.mp3,bsong.mp3
```

If you wanted an array of filenames, you'd have to split the `file_names` value on commas in your php code.

The order of terms returned by group_concat is undefined, but if order of filenames was important, you can embed a `order by` *within* the group_concat. For example, for alphabetical ordering use:

```
group_concat(file_name order by file_name) as file_names
```

or for file creation order use:

```
group_concat(file_name order by file_id) as file_names
```

Comment: I didn't end up needing this in the end, but +1 for an extremely useful function I wasn't aware of! Cheers.